# HTTP error 411 with Luigi central scheduler

Tags: python, http-error, luigi

As the title says, I am trying to run `luigi` with a centralized scheduler. I simply run `luigid` and the scheduler starts. I check `localhost:8082/` and I get the page as expected, empty as there are so far no jobs.

Then I start my little test program. It is not able to connect to the scheduler, giving the error 
`HTTPError: 411 Client Error: Length Required for url:http://localhost:8082/api/ping`

I am running `Linux 4.4.0-104`, Python version `2.7.12` and Luigi version `2.7.1`.

Here is my little test program that takes an integer *n* as input. First all files up to that number is written to a file. Then the next task does the same, but for the squared of the numbers

```
import luigi

class PrintNumbers(luigi.Task):
    n = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return []

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("numbers_up_to_{}.txt".format(self.n))

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            for i in range(1, self.n+1):
                f.write("{}\n".format(i))

class SquareNumbers(luigi.Task):
    n = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return [PrintNumbers(n=self.n)]

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("squares_up_to_{}.txt".format(self.n))

    def run(self):
        with self.input()[0].open() as fin, self.output().open('w') as fout:
            for line in fin:
                n = int(line.strip())
                out = n*n
                fout.write("{}:{}\n".format(n,out))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.run(['--n', '100000'], main_task_cls=SquaredNumbers)
```

Edit: Added a `luigi.cfg` file in the work directory:
I created a `luigi.cfg` in my work directory with the following:

```
[core]
default-scheduler-host=localhost
default-scheduler-port=8082
max-reschedules=2
parallel-scheduling=true
rpc-connect-timeout=10.0
```

Comment: Could you share your luigi.cfg content please ? (Feel free to hide away critical data)

Comment: It appears I don't have any such file. I looked in '/etc/luigi/', working directory and echoed '$LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH'.
Is there a way to just create a default one, or are there any specific things I should take note to adjust in there?

Comment: You can just create a `luigi.cfg` file in your project folder and make sure you include a `[core]` section with the host and port parameters like here:
https://github.com/groupon/luigi-warehouse/blob/master/luigi.cfg-example#L10

Comment: I added a `luigi.cfg` in the work directory, but I still receive the same error. I adjusted the port number to make sure that the file is read in, and it is correct.